# Multiplos components react dando erro!

Tags: react

Estou construindo minha primeira aplicação com React e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

```
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/Nav/Index';
import Main from './components/Main';

function App() {
  return (
    <><Nav /><Main /></>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tenho dois components o Nav e o Main, todos os dois estão devidamente importados, porém não consigo reenderizar os dois juntos.
se eu remover o encapsulamento jsx e o Main o component Nav aparecerá normalmente.

OBS: não apresenta nenhum erro no terminal do vscode

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Após bater a cabeça percebi que o react deixa a tela branca caso um dos components estejam vazios, então no componente Main eu coloquei

```
import React from "react";

const Main = () => {
    return(
        <main>
            <h1>Main</h1>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

E automáticamente a Nav e a Main apareceram na tela!